# Optimize a simple program

Tags: java, formula

So I've programmed for a while and Im a bit confused on how important it is for programs to be "well formatted" I wrote this simple formula program. How can it be "better" written ? In the program you can input some numbers for Einsteins time dilation equation and it outputs how much time has been dilated after a certain amount of time.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.lang.Math;

public class Yass {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static double velocity;
static double time;
static double dilated_time;
static double dilated_time_Minutes;
static double dilated_time_Hours;
static double dilated_time_Days;
static double dilated_time_Years;
static boolean timeIsSeconds = false;
static boolean timeIsMinutes = false;
static boolean timeIsHours = false;
static boolean timeIsDays = false;
static boolean timeIsYears = false;
public static final double c = 299792.458; // km/s


//Time in seconds, velocity in kilometers/second

public Yass(){

    getInput();
    executeEquation(time, velocity, c);

}


public void executeEquation(double t, double v, double c) {

    dilated_time = t / (Math.sqrt(1 - (Math.pow(v, 2) / Math.pow(c, 2))));

    if(dilated_time <= 60){
        timeIsSeconds = true;
    }
    if(dilated_time > 60 && dilated_time < (60*60)){
        dilated_time_Minutes = dilated_time / 60;
        timeIsMinutes = true;
    }
    if(dilated_time > (60*60) && dilated_time < (60*60)*24){
        dilated_time_Hours = (dilated_time / 60) / 60;
        timeIsHours = true;
    }
    if(dilated_time > (60*60)*24 && dilated_time < ((60*60)*24)*365){
        dilated_time_Days = ((dilated_time / 60) / 60) / 24;
        timeIsDays = true;
    }
    if(dilated_time > ((60*60)*24)*365){
        dilated_time_Years = (((dilated_time / 60) / 60) / 24) / 365;
        timeIsYears = true;
    }
}


public void getInput(){
    System.out.println("Enter the time you want to measure(stationary) in seconds: ");
    time = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("\n Enter velocity in km/s: ");
    velocity = sc.nextDouble();
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    new Yass();

    if(timeIsSeconds){
        System.out.println("So if you're in a spaceship and travel at " + velocity + 
                " km/s. And start a clock who'll measure " + time + " seconds.\nBut at the same time a stationary spaceship start an exact same clock"
                        + " at the same time and measure\nthe same amount of time. After the moving spaceship have measured " + time + " seconds. Then "
                                + "the stationary\nspaceship will have measured " + dilated_time + " seconds. And therefore time has been running slower for the moving spaceship.");
    }
    if(timeIsMinutes){
        System.out.println("So if you're in a spaceship and travel at " + velocity + 
                " km/s. And start a clock who'll measure " + time + " seconds.\nBut at the same time a stationary spaceship start an exact same clock"
                        + " at the same time and measure\nthe same amount of time. After the moving spaceship have measured " + time + " seconds. Then "
                                + "the stationary\nspaceship will have measured " + dilated_time_Minutes + " minutes. And therefore time has been running slower for the moving spaceship.");
    }
    if(timeIsHours){
        System.out.println("So if you're in a spaceship and travel at " + velocity + 
                " km/s. And start a clock who'll measure " + time + " seconds.\nBut at the same time a stationary spaceship start an exact same clock"
                        + " at the same time and measure\nthe same amount of time. After the moving spaceship have measured " + time + " seconds. Then "
                                + "the stationary\nspaceship will have measured " + dilated_time_Hours + " hours. And therefore time has been running slower for the moving spaceship.");
    }
    if(timeIsDays){
        System.out.println("So if you're in a spaceship and travel at " + velocity + 
                " km/s. And start a clock who'll measure " + time + " seconds.\nBut at the same time a stationary spaceship start an exact same clock"
                        + " at the same time and measure\nthe same amount of time. After the moving spaceship have measured " + time + " seconds. Then "
                                + "the stationary\nspaceship will have measured " + dilated_time_Days + " days. And therefore time has been running slower for the moving spaceship.");
    }
    if(timeIsYears){
        System.out.println("So if you're in a spaceship and travel at " + velocity + 
                " km/s. And start a clock who'll measure " + time + " seconds.\nBut at the same time a stationary spaceship start an exact same clock"
                        + " at the same time and measure\nthe same amount of time. After the moving spaceship have measured " + time + " seconds. Then "
                                + "the stationary\nspaceship will have measured " + dilated_time_Years + " years. And therefore time has been running slower for the moving spaceship.");
    }
}
}
```

Example:

Enter the time you want to measure(stationary) in seconds:
10

Enter velocity in km/s: 
270000

So if you're in a spaceship and travel at 270000.0 km/s. And start a clock who'll measure 10.0 seconds.
But at the same time a stationary spaceship start an exact same clock at the same time and measure
the same amount of time. After the moving spaceship have measured 10.0 seconds. Then the stationary
spaceship will have measured 23.009606245564093 seconds. And therefore time has been running slower for the moving spaceship.

Comment: Stationary to what frame of reference? Also, what exactly are you trying to optimize for? Size, speed or code density?

Comment: And the question is? By the way if you are looking for a code review here a better site : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note: `v * v` not only shorter than `Math.pow(v, 2)` but is also much faster.

Comment: When using `double` you should round your results.

Answer (score 2):

A few things pop out.

1. Make C-squared constant (i.e., static final) as well, instead of
   computing it every time.
2. Don't accept "c" as an input into execute equation method
3. Make a separate method that takes a long parameter in seconds and returns a descriptive string in the largest applicable units (e.g., 1000000 => "11.57 days").  In this function, check for years first, so in the subsequent checks you only need to check if the parameter is greater than a number instead of between two numbers.
4. Get rid of the series of "if" statements in the main method and have only one, which calls the new function in #3 above.

Answer (score 0):

First is to improve readibility by using javadoc:

```
    /**
     * Calculates the result of Einsteins time dilation equation. 
     * @param t time in seconds
     * @param v speed in km/s
     * @param c light speed constant
     */
    public void executeEquation(double t, double v, double c) {

    }
```

- Use a formatter for correct identing (Ctrl-Shift-F ) in eclipse.
- The variable v normally has the unit  m/s. If you use kilomter/s you might rename it: double vKmPerSec. This should be done for all units that are not
  in SI (International System) units (meter, second, kg).
- "Yass" is for me not an obvious class name. rename it to something more descriptive.
- class Yass has no comments, you might add yourself as author
- The results should not be stored in static variables. "dilated_time"

It would be better to use a result class:

```
class EinsteinResult {
         // here you store dilated_time, etc.
}
```

and return that result in

```
EinsteinResult executeEquation(double t, double v, double c) {
      //... 
      return EinsteinResult;
}
```

and as Peter Lawrey commented, replace `Math.pow(c,2)` with `c*c`